# What's wrong with this circuit to convert 0-5V to +10/-10V

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential-amplifier

I'm trying to come up with a solution to use the analog output of a DAC to drive the X-Y axis control of a commercially available laser 'closed-loop moving magnet' driver.

I found an explanation on how to use an op-amp to create a differential amplifier [here](http://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/the-differential-amplifier-common-mode-error-part-1/) and a calculator [here](http://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/differential-amplifier-output-common-mode-voltage-calculator/), but I can't get that to work without a 2.5V reference voltage.

I also found a simpler design for such a circuit [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=l0qiptlmujeikl1ldfblrm7j13&topic=153837.msg1155389#msg1155389), but when I try that in a simulator (I use iCircuit on my iPad) it doesn't swing from -10V to 10V but from -8V to 12V (approximately). This is the circuit:

[image]

This is my testing in iCircuit:

[image]

Tried it with the included circuit simulator, don't know how it works exactly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvQtCa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is, is this simpler design the way to go, but are my resistor values wrong? Or do I need to go with the first circuit design but need to add something to get a 2.5V reference?

I have very little information on the exact electrical requirements of the scanner, but I'm assuming it's a product designed to be used in an ILDA laser device and fairly compatible to that standard.

**UPDATE** In iCircuit, I replaced the lower 10K resistor with 20K and the feedback resistor from 15K to 30K, and it looks like I'm getting the desired output now. Still, I don't know if this is trustworthy or not.

Bonus question: I have an ST LM324N opamp lying around from an old lab kit. Do you consider this device suitable for this task, if I supply +12V/-12V to it?

Comment: What is the reference voltage? Are you measuring everything against the ground?

Comment: Yes, I believe in iCircuit, I measure against ground. Perhaps I should try and include the iCircuit circuit here.

Comment: Why not use a 4-quadrant DAC in the first place?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because I have no idea what that is. I'm a binary guy *grin*. I want a 12-bit SPI DAC that I can control from my Arduino at high speed, and that's commonly available on a breakout board or in a DIP package (for prototyping). I don't even know if such a device exists.

Comment: The MicroChip [MCP4921](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21897a.pdf) is a 12 bit DAC with an SPI interface, and [available in DIP-8](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-MCP4921-E-P-12-Bit-DAC-with-SPI-TM-Interface-DIP8-/221273600018?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3384ef3012) packages.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh yes, that's a nice one, considering the LDAC feature. It doesn't do -10/+10V though.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I bought an MCP4922 in DIP package and got it working. Also, I may only need -5V to 5V which considerably simplifies the opamp design. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your circuit is incorrect.  What you are trying to do is a gain+offset (negative offset) so you want to gain it up and offset the virtual ground point. You don't need that 10k/10k voltage divider as you've drawn it to provide a 2.5V reference.

Since your full scale output from the DAC is 5V, and you want a full scale output from the opamp of 20V (-10 to +10) then you need to have a gain of 4 in the opamp. That gives you 0-20V. So you want (DAC x Gain) - Offset.

In a non-inverting op-amp, the + input has a gain set by the (feedback resistor/input resistor)+1.  However, the negative input has a gain of simply the (feedback resistor/input resistor).  So a non-inverting input with a gain of 4 will have a a gain of 3 from the negative input.  You can use the negative input to offset the fullscale 20V to -10 to +10.  So you want 10/3 = 3.33 volts at the negative input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fghc2b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At the point I marked 3.333V, for a standard non-inverting op-amp configuration, that point would be GND. But you want to add the negative input's gain to the output too, so you need 3.333V there.

The LM324 will work fine,but it's not a precision opamp and has some significant input offsets itself, and you might lose precision of the DAC input, but it can be trimmed out if you need to. If you don't want to trim anything then you can use a precision opamp with good DC characteristics.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to simulate that. Would you care to answer my bonus question? Can I try this on my LM324N?

Comment: I just edited to add that.

Comment: Also note that the LM324 can only go to 1.5V below the top rail, and can get close to the bottom rail, so you need to use at least -10.5 to +11.5V on the LM324.

Comment: This circuit will not work. The current through R1 will make your 3.33V reference not 3.33V. In simulation, the output goes down to about -8V, and clips against the positive rail.

Comment: Yes, that 3.333 needs to be low impedance, i.e. a buffered reference.I've updated the circuit drawing, thanks!

Comment: That circuit looks like it would work now, but I find the discussion confusing. The 3.3V offset doesn't add gain, and I'm not sure what you mean by this circuit having both inverting and non-inverting gain.

Comment: oh, the 3.3V at the negative input, so it has negative gain of Rf/Rg = 30k/10k = 3. So 3.3 x -3 = -10. This is added to the positive gain from the non-inverting input, which is going to be at max DAC 5 x 4 = 20.  20 + (-10) = 10 Max out. At DAC(min)=0, then it will be (0 x 4) + (3.33 x -3) = -10.

Comment: One more thing... All opamps have both inverting and non-inverting gain. We usually just draw one input to a ground reference, so it doesn't contribute and we only see either the inverting gain or the non-inverting gain uniquely. But both gains are there at the same time, and we can use that to our advantage in interesting ways.

Comment: Thank you. This works indeed. I think I understand the circuit, but can I ask what R5 is for?

Comment: I just put a typical value there. You'll want to put something between 1k and 10k.  The usual reason you want to put a resistor after a DAC and going into an opamp is that the resistor + the opamp's input capacitance will form an RC filter to limit bandwidth to something that is useful for your application. The LM324 is not known for its good specs, and I can't even find its input capacitance. So let's assume its not very good, and so assume its around 1nF.  So the 10k+1nF limits the BW to around 16Khz. Since the LM324 has 1Mhz BW product, at a gain of 4 it's already BW limited anyways@250kHz

Comment: furthermore, you always need to watch out for opamp input bias currents when you have an input resistor.  The LM324 has 20nA typical input bias current, and this will drop a voltage across the 10k input resistor, V=IR = 20nA * 10K = 200uV ...so if you can't afford 200uV, you might want to use 1k there.

Answer (score 1):

this is the best circuit to rescale the DAC output volt from 0:5 v to -10:10 v using ad8033aks op-amp which has a high fast response up to 80mhz , high accuracy and without any offset

the rv1 potentiometer simulate the DAC output
[image: when DAC output reach the 5v the output changed to +10v]

[image: when DAC output reach the 0v the output changed to -10v]

[image: when DAC output reach the 2.5v the output changed to 0v]